# Backbone route with unlimited optional parameters

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-routing

In my app, I have two important models: ContentCollection and ContentItem.

Each ContentCollection has many ContentCollections and ContentItems. You can think of ContentCollections as folders, and ContentItems as files. So, this kind of structure needs to be possible:

```
-  ContentCollection
   \- ContentCollection
      \- ContentCollection
         \- ContentCollection
            \- Item
            \- Item
      \- ContentCollection
         \- Item
-  ContentCollection
   \- Item
   \- Item
-  Item
-  Item
```

I want to create show routes for both ContentCollections and ContentItems.

```
/home/collections/{id}
```

and...

```
/home/items/{id}
```

and...

```
/home/collections/{id}/collections/{id}/collections/{id}
```

and...

```
/home/collections/{id}/collections/{id}/collections/{id}/items/{id}
```

and so on.

Is there a simple way for me to elegantly handle for this sort of nesting in a backbone route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a catch-all route, which matches anything...

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  '*collection': 'showCollection'
});
```

And then a little bit of parsing in your action:

```
Controller = {
  showCollection: function (query) {
    segments = query.split('/')
  }
}
```